# Is it possible to color the prompt in Bash?

Tags: bash, customization

Is it possible to color the prompt ("user@host:~/dir/$") in Bash? Some commands generate a lot of output and it's sometimes hard to find where it started. Coloring would help a lot.

Comment: Yes you can.See this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found an easy way to do it:

Uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That's certainly the easiest way :)

Comment: I absolutely overlooked this option in the ~/.bashrc! Thanx anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Bashish is a theme engine for the console; check some screen shots [here](http://bashish.sourceforge.net/screenshot.html) **:-)**

It's easy to install:

1. Click on the [download link](http://bashish.sourceforge.net/download.html) on the website
2. get the deb for Ubuntu
3. double-click the downloaded file and Software center will install it for you.

After that, close any open terminals and type:

```
bashish list
```

to get a list of already built themes.

Have fun **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

A catch-all alternative to the other solutions:

```bash
if [ $(which dircolors) ]
then
  if [ -r ~/.dircolors ]
  then
    eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)"
  else
    eval "$(dircolors -b)"
  fi
  export color_support=true
fi
```

Additionally, you could enable colors in common commands such as `ls` and `grep`.

```bash
if [ "$color_support" = true ]
then
  alias ls="ls --color=auto"
  alias grep="grep --color=auto"
fi
```

Comment: In what files should that code be stored?

Comment: I suggest `.bashrc` for simplicity. :)