# Terminal Headline Bold and With Color Like Linux Mint

Tags: customization, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to color the prompt in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13892/is-it-possible-to-color-the-prompt-in-bash)

in the past i've been using linux mint, but i'm back on ubuntu, and i like to know how to put the terminal Headline (the User@COMPUTERNAME:~$) in bold and with color like linux mint.

this is particulary usefull to me becouse i use a terminal in the widget layer of compiz.

thanks for the help

Comment: Although a great question, I'm afraid I've had to close it because it is very similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13892/is-it-possible-to-color-the-prompt-in-bash) one. Hopefully you can have your question answered there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your question is very similar to this one: 
[Is it possible to color the prompt in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13892/is-it-possible-to-color-the-prompt-in-bash)

There are a couple of answers there already.