# Displaying colors in the prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

How to display my prompt in color? I see a lot of text go up my screen, and a lot of crud. Something like `(red)myName(red)@(blue)myMachine:~$(blue)` would help simplify things a lot.

Comment: You should write one question per post, answering multiple questions is confusing and it doesn't allow to properly account for that is answered already.

Comment: About the prompt colors, check the following link:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

Comment: ok, ill edit it and create another one. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Duplicate question with http://askubuntu.com/questions/13892/is-it-possible-to-color-the-prompt-in-bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to color the prompt in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13892/is-it-possible-to-color-the-prompt-in-bash)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just edit your `~/.bashrc` file and remove the hash (`#`) from the line:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

Save the file, and from then on, your newly-opened shells will be colored.