# Terminal: Change the color of my hostname and username

Tags: command-line, bash, personalization, ps1

When using the terminal, I want both my username and my hostname to have separate color schemes.
Is that possible with Ubuntu's default terminal emulator(if not, is it possible in terminator?)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13892/is-it-possible-to-color-the-prompt-in-bash and the link it connects to: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap `\h` in, e.g., `\[\033[01;31m\]` and `\[\033[00m\]` in `~/.bashrc`'s `$PS1` definition to make the host red; `\[\033[00m\]`, which resets all the attributes, is already there in the default prompt, so you won't really need it, and I suggest commenting out `$PS1`'s definition and adding a line right after rather than editing the current `$PS1`'s definition for an easy rollback:

```bsh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

This should work out-of-the-box on e.g. `gnome-terminal`; on `xterm` (and I'd guess in general on `xterm`-based terminals), you'll also have to uncomment this line:

```bsh
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

You can check out other available colors e.g. [here](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).

Comment: Does that work for the terminal application?

Comment: @MarioKamenjak It works for all terminals that support coloring through ANSI color escape sequences (for example the console, `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`, but most if not all `xterm`-based terminals will likely support that, though the palette could be more or less extensive). I suppose you're referring to Terminal (which is `gnome-terminal`), so if that's the case yeah, it will work for Terminal.

Comment: I had to uncomment force_color_prompt first.  Anyway, it works now. Here is my color scheme:
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;33m\]\u\[\033[01;36m\]@\[\033[01;36m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[00m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'

Comment: This helped as well:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/
I will accept your answer now.

Comment: @MarioKamenjak Which terminal? It shouldn't be necessary in `gnome-terminal` / `xterm` (in fact my prompt is colored, but `force_color_prompt=yes` is still commented).

Comment: @MarioKamenjak Ah I see, apparently it's actually required in `xterm` (and I'd guess also in `xterm`-based terminals?). Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.